# Why does my Emacs shell render this gunk?

Tags: emacs

In my emacs shell, I see this output:

^[[J~% echo $PS1
echo $PS1
%2c%%

On my other machine, this stuff doesn't show up at all. Can anyone suggest a reason why and how to fix it?

Comment: I'd test the shells, do `echo $0` in both windows, make sure the shells are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your shell startup script is configuring the `PS1` variable to output [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) as part of the prompt (perhaps to do colorized text or reverse video).  An Emacs buffer can't do those things (at least not with escape sequences), so instead you see the raw escape sequence.  You should be able to test the value of environment variable `TERM` in your shell startup code that is setting `PS1`.  If the value of variable `TERM` is `emacs`, then don't insert the escape sequences into `PS1`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try going to the shell buffer and doing `M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on`.